# Xamarin Forms Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, permissions, android-camera, runtimeexception

I am trying to implement a copy of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-contentpage/. The downloaded source file works fine.
But when I try to run my code which I copied from it, it always give me the below error. I have added the necessary permissions in manifest also.

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

[image]

Comment: did you request permission to use the camera?

Comment: @Jason No. But I added permissions on manifest.xml

Comment: you need to request permissions at runtime

Comment: @Jason How to add?

Comment: The downloaded sample works because it's targeting API 19, which asks for permissons at [install time](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#install-time_requests_android_511_and_below). I'm guessing you're targeting API 23 or higher which means you have to [prompt for permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#runtime_requests_android_60_and_higher). [Xamarin Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android) will help you with prompting for permissions.

Comment: @Andrew Yes that was what I have missed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a conclusion of the comments:

You need to `request permissions` at runtime when you want to use camera in Android project.

To request permissions, you can use [Xamarin.Essentials: Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android):

```
 var status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.Camera>();
```

There are also many other permission request information in the document.